# Виджет на рабочем столе на PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Ну вот например есть основная программа, и в ней хочу вызывать отдельные окна, которые располагались бы на рабочем столе. То есть я хочу её видеть на нём, когда сворачиваю все окна кнопкой "свернуть все окна" в нижнем левом углу.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel
from threading import Thread


class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('main')
        self.move(0,0)

        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('background2.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint )
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        self.show()

        self.widget = TimerWidget()
        self.widget.show()


class TimerWidget(QWidget, Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Timer')

        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('background2.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint )
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста ваш пример, который у вас есть и объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Накидал напримерный вариант.